# Does Chrome use WinInet?

Tags: google-chrome

I think it used to, but am not sure if it still does. (does Chrome use WinInet.DLL on Windows?) Does anyone know, definitively, and if it doesn't use it anymore, which version did it change on?  I'm on a conf call trying to troubleshoot connectivity with an app that uses WinInet. Connectivity test (painting the WSDL) works with Chrome but not IE.  Thanks!

Comment: You might find what you need here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack  It does look like they still use the winInet for proxy resolution: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/proxy-settings-fallback

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Dependecy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine this.

It doesn't seem to directly reference `wininet.dll`.

[image]

But, sooner or later, it'll be somewhere in the tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not use WinInet. I just attached the debugger to **chrome.exe** and no `wininet.dll` in the loaded modules.

Comment: It is on my system, using Process Explorer a file handle search for Wininet.dll shows many Chrome instances.